# How to test Kafka Consumer with @KafkaListener and Mockito?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-boot-test, spring-kafka-test

I need to test Kafka Consumer. In the folder with the tests, I create application.property in which I describe the Producer.

Here are my Consumer settings in main folder:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:29092
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=info
```

My Consumer should read the message and save it to the database:

```
@Component("kafkaConsumer")
public class KafkaConsumerExchangeRate {

    private final ExchangeRepository repository;

    public KafkaConsumerExchangeRate(ExchangeRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @KafkaListener(
            topics = {"exchange-rate"},
            properties = {"spring.json.value.default.type = ru.company.service.exchange_rate.controller.dto.ListExchangeRatesDto"}
    )
    public void listenMessages(ConsumerRecord<String, ListExchangeRatesDto> record) {
        List<ExchangeOutgoingRateDto> exchangesRates = record.value().getExchangesRates();
        for (ExchangeOutgoingRateDto dto : exchangesRates) {
            ExchangeRate rate = repository
                    .findExchangeRateByCurrency1AndCurrency2(dto.getCurrency1(), dto.getCurrency2())
                    .orElseThrow();

            rate.setBuyingRate(dto.getBuyingRate());
            rate.setSellingRate(dto.getSellingRate());
            rate.setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime.parse(dto.getUpdateAt()));

            repository.save(rate);
        }
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092"})
class KafkaConsumerExchangeRateTest {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, ListExchangeRatesDto> template;

    @Mock
    private ExchangeRepository repository;

    @InjectMocks
    @Qualifier("kafkaConsumer")
    private KafkaConsumerExchangeRate consumer;

    @Test
    void givenEmbeddedKafkaBroker_whenSendingWithSimpleProducer_thenMessageReceived()
            throws InterruptedException {

        //given
        ExchangeRate exchangeRate = ExchangeRate.builder()
                .buyingRate(BigDecimal.ONE)
                .sellingRate(BigDecimal.TEN)
                .updatedAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .currency1("EUR")
                .currency2("USD")
                .build();

        ExchangeOutgoingRateDto dto = ExchangeOutgoingRateDto.builder()
                .buyingRate(BigDecimal.ONE)
                .sellingRate(BigDecimal.TEN)
                .updateAt(LocalDateTime.now().toString())
                .currency1("EUR")
                .currency2("USD")
                .build();

        ListExchangeRatesDto listOfDtos = ListExchangeRatesDto.builder()
                .exchangesRates(List.of(dto))
                .build();

        //and
        doReturn(Optional.of(exchangeRate)).when(repository)
                .findExchangeRateByCurrency1AndCurrency2(anyString(), anyString());

        //when
        template.send("exchange-rate", listOfDtos);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //then
        verify(repository, times(1)).save(any());
    }
}
```

I was hoping that I could calculate that the save method would work once. But I come across an exception:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
repository.save(<any>);
-> at ru.company.service.exchange_rate.kafka.KafkaConsumerExchangeRateTest.givenEmbeddedKafkaBroker_whenSendingWithSimpleProducer_thenMessageReceived(KafkaConsumerExchangeRateTest.java:84)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I assume that the Consumer that is being created in the test and the Consumer that is actually being used are two different instances. Because the repository inside is not a mock and returns null when trying to get data.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing concerns which does not work together as is.

The `@Mock` has a scope of only this test class.
Then you use a `KafkaTemplate` from Spring application context to produce the testing data. The Spring knows nothing about your mock and just does the stuff against its beans, including your `@KafkaListener`.

The Mockito does not interfere with Spring so easy.

Instead you need to do:

```
@MockBean
private ExchangeRepository repository;
```

And you don't need `@InjectMocks`.
Spring Boot Testing framework will perform pre-processing for the application context to create mocks for those properties and replace respective beans in the application context. Then this mock is injected into your `KafkaConsumerExchangeRate` regular Spring way. And you are good to proceed with your stubs and verifications!

Comment: Unfortunately, this exception still appears with @MockBean.

Comment: I think `Thread.sleep(1000);` is not enough. The consumption in your `@KafkaListener` happens on the other thread, so you have to wait until the data travels from the producer to consumer, or have a loop until verification is fulfilled.

Comment: You're right, it needed more time. Thanks for the help!